# How to make animate drawing a border? (Vanilla JS solution needed)

Tags: css-animations

I am trying to build a relaxation app. 
For this I need to get a animation of border being drawn.
The way I tried is not giving a smooth transition.
How to achieve the same?
A part of javascript code and codepen link is shared below

https://codepen.io/TM06/pen/RwrRxLQ

JS

```
     if(count && seconds<=4){
    document.getElementById("message").innerText = "Breathe In";
    switch(seconds){
      case 1 :
        document.getElementById("container").style.borderTop = "8px solid red";
        break;
      case 2 : 
        document.getElementById("container").style.borderRight = "8px solid red";
        break;
      case 3 :
        document.getElementById("container").style.borderBottom = "8px solid red";
        break;
      case 4 : 
        document.getElementById("container").style.borderLeft = "8px solid red";
        break;
    }
  }else if(count === false && seconds< 5){
    document.getElementById("message").innerText = "Breathe Out";
    switch(seconds){
      case 1 :
        document.getElementById("container").style.borderLeft = "0px";
        break;
      case 2 : 
        document.getElementById("container").style.borderBottom = "0px";
        break;
      case 3 :
        document.getElementById("container").style.borderRight = "0px";
        break;
      case 4 : 
        document.getElementById("container").style.borderTop = "0px";
        break;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have acheived the border animation. Sharing the codepen link here:
https://codepen.io/TM06/pen/wvMgeaw

```
<div class="container h-100  align-items-center" id="container">
<div class="topBar" id="topBar"></div> 
<div class="rightBar" id="rightBar"></div>
<div class="bottomBar" id="bottomBar"></div>
<div class="meter9"><span class="leftBar" id="leftBar"></span></div>
```

This is not yet perfect though.